# How should I join these two tables? is it outer join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

Table A

```
Table_A
+------+-----+--------+
| Name | Age | Weight |
+------+-----+--------+
| John | 20  | 200    |
+------+-----+--------+
| Jack | 15  | 180    |
+------+-----+--------+

 Table_B
+------+-------+-------+
| Name | Music | Eyes  |
+------+-------+-------+
| John | Rock  | Blue  |
+------+-------+-------+
| Jack | Rap   | Green |
+------+-------+-------+
```

I want to add the `weight` column to Table B so end up with something like:

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| Name | Music | Eyes  | Weight |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| John | Rock  | Blue  | 200    |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
| Jack | Rap   | Green | 100    |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I am new to SQL and trying to learn join syntax. Is it:

```
SELECT Table_A.weight, Table_B.Name, Table_B.music, Table_B.eyes 
FROM Table_B
LEFT JOIN Table_A 
    on Table_A.name = Table_B.name
```

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: yes syntax right but there's value mismatch because of 100 vs. 180. Btw prefer using aliases such as `Table_B b` or `Table_A a`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, what does 'a' and 'b' represent?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax works, but an outer join is not needed for this example.  There is an exact match in the key values between the tables.

I recommend also that you use table aliases in your query:

```
SELECT a.weight, b.Name, b.music, b.eyes 
FROM Table_B b JOIN
     Table_A a
     ON a.name = b.name;
```

You would use a `LEFT JOIN` if there were rows in `b` that are not in `a` *and* you wanted them in the result set.

Comment: Side note: I'd add that a meaningless alias (like 'a' or 'b') greatly reduces readability because you won't know what a random single character like 'a' or 'b' is referring to without repeatedly slogging back through your joins.  If you're stuck with poorly named tables, then a meaningful alias like 'Person' or 'Invoice' would definitely be beneficial.